# Accessing response status in Google Visualization API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In the dummy code below, cribbed in general from Google's API examples, there are three functions - two that are "required" by the API and one RunMe() that kicks it off. If a spreadsheet request is invalid, I can access the error message it returns from the handleQueryResponse() function. But for my purposes, I need to be able to test for the existence of response.isError() from within the runMe() function. This seems simple, but I can't seem to get at that response object from outside of handleQueryResponse(). This may be due to my JavaScript newbie status or because the API does something weird.

I  also find it weird that uncommenting console.log(query); in the getTableMeta() function produces an "Er" object that just seems to be a prototype, not a representation of the actual query.

Thanks for suggestions.

The spreadsheet ID below is invalid with the "z" at the end and valid with it removed.

```
function runMe() {
    var foo = getTableMeta('0AtP_YtDJ532RdDcxZUl6Zkl4YkxKcEYzbld4ZDA4SlEz');
    // console.log(response);
    // console.log(response.getMessage());
    // console.log(foo.getMessage());
}  


// Get table metadata from Google
function getTableMeta(spreadsheet_id) {

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=' + spreadsheet_id);
    // console.log(query);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse); 
    }       


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        // alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage() + '. Please click Previous and enter a different spreadsheet ID.');
        console.log(response.getMessage());
    }    
    return response;
}   

runMe();
```

[API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get the value in the `runMe()` function. This is because the call it triggers is asynchronous; it simply sends off a request, whose response will be handled by the specified callback function, in your case `handleQueryResponse`.

I would look at runMe simply as a trigger; whatever logic you'd like to include in that function, instead focus on working it in to `handleQueryResponse`.

Hope that helps. Feel free to provide more context if I've misinterpreted something.

Comment: Thanks Oli - That explains a lot :) This was going to be a wizard UI and I was hoping to validate in the first step, but it sounds like I'll need to come up with a different UI for that. Appreciated.